# Are there any stunt jumps IN the water?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I'm trying to complete all the stunt jumps in GTA 5 Online (I assume they are the exact same jumps as in the single player). I have about 8 left to go, and I'm wondering: are there any stunt jumps that are in the water, that would require a water vehicle to complete the jump?

> There have been several jumps NEAR water, or that require jumping across water.

A quick Google search didn't reveal much more than pages and videos listing every jump. I'm not interested in spoiling their location and would rather not risk trawling through a page to find. Are there any stunt jumps that require a water vehicle to complete?

<sub>Although **I'd** rather not know their location, I understand a simple "yes/no" question wouldn't be *the best* answer. It is fine to link to any resources that will back your answer up, and if you wish to quote a resource or put the location of a jump (if any) prefer the spoiler tags</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have [successfully completed all stunt jumps in the game](https://socialclub.rockstargames.com/member/amphibiousone/feed/3123214258283726685) and received the *Show Off* achievement, and there are no stunt jumps **in** the water; that is, there are no stunt jumps that require a water vehicle to complete.

There are several stunt jumps that jump over water, but all jumps require a land vehicle to complete.